# How to merge in external changes to branch

Tags: git, merge

I am using Git with visual studio2017 and i currently need to merge external changes in a somewhat weird manner. I'm not sure how to go about this.

The story goes as follows. We started developing an app which in the beginning was not source controlled.

Then the app was copied and mailed to another company (FooCompany). They made additional changes to the app, mostly adding their own 'module' which is called Dryer.

I put the original project in the GIT version control and we kept developing as usual.

Now - a couple months later, the FooCompany sent back the project file(s) with the changes they made. I now have the task of merging these changes into our current software.

The software i work with has its own Diff/Merge tools(s) which i have to use, since some project configuration uses binary files. I have these tools setup to be used.

For this task I made the following branches

**Master**
The master branch with the current code.

**feature/dryer-integration**
A direct branch of master. I need to merge the code of FooCompany to this branch, not to master.

**dryer-code-raw**
I uploaded the code of FooCompany to this branch. I branched of master, then direct copied the files that were sent to me into this branch and committed this. This branch therefore contains very old code i'd like to be overwritten with from code within master, but also contains new code FooCompany made which i'd like to add to feature/dryer-integration.

So my question is:
How can I merge the outdated project with new changes in the dryer-code-raw branch into our actual software in the feature/dryer-integration branch using diff/merge tools?

Sidenote(s):

- Yes i know, that this should not be the usual way to go about things, but i did not have control over what happened before
- I mainly use basic GIT from within VS (which comes down to clicking 'sync'), so i'm not well versed in using GIT.